# Failed to get driver instance

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hsqldb, hikaricp

I'm new to Spring (Boot) and trying to get a pooled database connection to a HSQLDB server.

pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
        <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

myDataSource

```
@Bean
@Profile("devel")
public DataSource myDataSource() {
    HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
    config.setJdbcUrl("org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDataSource://localhost:9001/devel");
    config.setUsername("SA");
    HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource(config);
```

When the debugger reaches the last line it throws:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'myDataSource' defined in class path resource [com/pushforgo/config/AppConfigurationProd.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'myDataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to get driver instance for jdbcUrl=org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDataSource://localhost:9001/devel; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myDataSource' defined in class path resource [com/pushforgo/config/AppConfigurationProd.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'myDataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to get driver instance for jdbcUrl=org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDataSource://localhost:9001/devel
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:372) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1076) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:851) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:111) [spring-boot-test-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98) [spring-test-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116) [spring-test-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83) [spring-test-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117) [spring-test-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83) [spring-test-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.AutoConfigureReportTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(AutoConfigureReportTestExecutionListener.java:46) [spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230) [spring-test-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228) [spring-test-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287) [spring-test-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) [spring-test-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247) [spring-test-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94) [spring-test-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191) [spring-test-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192) [.cp/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myDataSource' defined in class path resource [com/pushforgo/config/AppConfigurationProd.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'myDataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to get driver instance for jdbcUrl=org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDataSource://localhost:9001/devel
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1054) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1019) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    ... 53 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'myDataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to get driver instance for jdbcUrl=org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDataSource://localhost:9001/devel
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    ... 67 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to get driver instance for jdbcUrl=org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDataSource://localhost:9001/devel
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.<init>(DriverDataSource.java:88) ~[HikariCP-2.4.7.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.initializeDataSource(PoolBase.java:298) ~[HikariCP-2.4.7.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.<init>(PoolBase.java:91) ~[HikariCP-2.4.7.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:101) ~[HikariCP-2.4.7.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:71) ~[HikariCP-2.4.7.jar:na]
    at com.pushforgo.config.AppConfigurationProd.myDataSource(AppConfigurationProd.java:24) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.pushforgo.config.AppConfigurationProd$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1172dd0e.CGLIB$myDataSource$0(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.pushforgo.config.AppConfigurationProd$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1172dd0e$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$2d3397d5.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at com.pushforgo.config.AppConfigurationProd$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1172dd0e.myDataSource(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    ... 68 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:315) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.<init>(DriverDataSource.java:81) ~[HikariCP-2.4.7.jar:na]
    ... 83 common frames omitted
```

I've already checked the database and can connect to it without any problem using a tool like Squirrel and the given JDBC string.

EDIT

After setting the URL and driverClassName I'm getting this

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'myDataSource' defined in class path resource [com/pushforgo/config/AppConfigurationProd.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'myDataSource' threw exception; nested exception is com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: connection exception: connection failure: java.io.EOFException; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myDataSource' defined in class path resource [com/pushforgo/config/AppConfigurationProd.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'myDataSource' threw exception; nested exception is com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: connection exception: connection failure: java.io.EOFException
```

Answer (score 8):

Your URL seems wrong. As far as I remember, it should be:

```
jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:9001/devel
```

And also, you didn't provide driver class name (`org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver`).

```
config.setDriverClassName("org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver");
```

If you are using Spring Boot 1.4, there's no need for explicit definition of data source when using HikariCP. As stated in [documentation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.4-Release-Notes#datasource-binding).

Answer (score 1):

`config.addDataSourceProperty("useSSL",false);` may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/dbproperties-chapt.html), the correct line should be

```
config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:9001/devel");
```